# style sheet for check box only for ie8

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I want different css for ie 8, i am doing like this but not working

```
/* for all browsers other than IE. */
input[type=checkbox]
{
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: url(../../images/uncheck.png) no-repeat right;
}


<!--[if IE 8]>
input[type=checkbox]
{
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can't have conditional comments inside the css. Also, remove `-webkit-apperance` as it won't even be applied in IE, since it doesn't use the `webkit` rendering engine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

You need to mention css properties inside `<style>`

Add the following in `head` tag of HTML file but not in css file or in other `<style` tag.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style>
        input[type=checkbox] {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 1.2em;
            /* -webkit-appearance: none; */
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

For more information, go through this **[link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)**

```
 document.head.innerHTML += "the above text here"; //not sure whether this will fix that or not.
```

Comment: @AltafSami add this code in `head` tag of html file. Not in css file.

Comment: i added in my view as i am working on mvc4, its not working :(

Comment: You're not overriding anything, you are applying the same styles, try adding `border:10px solid red` to the IE8 conditional rule, and see if it shows up.

Comment: @AltafSami If you want to call it as code then use `document.head.innerHTML`. Check my updated post.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

In your HTML, do something like this:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css"></link>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
```

Then put your IE8 css in `ie8.css`. You can't have conditional comments within the actual `.css` file

**Solution 2**

or change your `DOCTYPE` to :

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

So you can do `.lt-ie9 .your-class` and it will be applied to IE8 and under.

Comment: for one class i should create different css? there is no other option?

Comment: You want to keep your css fixes separate, so having another stylesheet for IE fixes is OK.

Comment: i don't want to create seperate stylesheet for ie, other all things are working fine in all browsers. There is only this check box issue, so i want to fix it using css class.

Comment: OK, then check `solution 2` in my post.